# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Vendor\Modulename\Model\Doccountmodel::create

Tags: magento2

I have created a crud model for a custom table in a  module but when I have called that model to do operations. I am getting an error

```
public function __construct(Context $context , \Vendor\Modulename\Model\Doccountmodel $doccountfactory,  Session $customerSession)
    {
    
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->doccountfactory = $doccountfactory;
        parent::__construct ( $context );
    }

public function execute(){
  $sampleModel = $this->doccountfactory->create();


    // Load the item with ID is 1
    $item = $sampleModel->load(1);
    var_dump($item->getData());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in your your `__construct` signature this

```
\Vendor\Modulename\Model\Doccountmodel $doccountfactory
```

with this

```
\Vendor\Modulename\Model\DoccountmodelFactory $doccountfactory
```

Comment: Getting so many errors Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Customer\DocCount::__construct() must be an instance of Vendor\Modulename\Model\DoccountmodelFactory, instance of Vendor\Modulename\Model\Doccountmodel given, called in

Comment: clear the contents of `generated/code`

Comment: Yes it is working after clear the generated/code. One more doubt How Factory  working

Comment: read this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html and this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/factories.html